# How to prove gcd of consecutive Fibonacci numbers is 1?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, fibonacci-numbers, gcd-and-lcm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prove that two any consecutive terms of Fibonacci sequence are relatively prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24378/prove-that-two-any-consecutive-terms-of-fibonacci-sequence-are-relatively-prime)

How to prove it ? Can you help me ?

Let $f_n$ be Fibonacci Sequence.
$$(f_{n},f_{n+1})=1,\quad \forall\,n\in\mathbb{N}.$$
Here $(a,b)$ is the greatest common divisor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ Put $\rm\:a_n = 1 = b_n\:$ in the much more general result below.

**Theorem** $\ $ If $\rm\:(\color{#c00}{b_n,\,f_n) = 1}\:$ and $\rm\:f_{n+1} = a_n f_n + b_n f_{n-1}\:$ then $\rm\:(f_{n+1},\,f_n) = (f_1,\,f_0).$

**Proof** $\ $ Clear if $\rm\:n = 0.\:$ Else by Euclid and induction we have

$$\rm (f_{n+1},\,f_n) = (a_n f_n\! +\! \color{}{b_n} f_{n-1},\,f_n) = (\color{#c00}{b_n} f_{n-1},\, \color{#c00}{f_n}) = (f_{n-1},\,f_n) = (f_1,\,f_0)\qquad$$

**Remark** $ $ Similarly [we can prove](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/60353/242) much more generally that the Fibonacci numbers  $\rm\:f_n\:$ comprise a [*strong* divisibility sequence:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_sequence) $\rm\, (f_m,f_n) = f_{(m,n)},\:$ i.e. $\rm\:gcd(f_m,f_n) = f_{\gcd(m,n)}.$ OP is case $\rm\,m=n\!+\!1.$

Comment: Can we make a similar statement about $(a_n, f_n)$? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527015

Answer (score 12):

You could use induction.

First show $(f_2,f_1) = 1$.  Then for $n \geq 2$, assume $(f_n,f_{n-1}) = 1$.  Use this and the recursion $f_{n + 1} = f_n + f_{n - 1}$ to show $(f_{n + 1},f_n) = 1$.

Answer (score 9):

If a $d\in\mathbb{N}$ divides $f_n$ and $f_{n+1}$, then $d$ divides also the difference of these two, $f_{n+1}-f_n=f_{n-1}$. Then using $f_n-f_{n-1}=f_{n-2}$, we get $d\mid f_{n-2}$. Repeating this argument again and again, we'll get $d\mid f_{n-3}$, $d\mid f_{n-4}$, and at the end, $d\mid f_{1}$. But $f_1=1$, therefore $d=1$.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: Euclidean algorithm and the recursive definition of the Fibonacci sequence.