# Prove by induction $T_n$ is odd

Tags: discrete-mathematics

### Taken from MIT's OpenCourseWare site for Discrete Math:

> **We deﬁne the following recurrence for $n ≥ 0$:** 
>   $$T_{n+2} = T_{n+1} + 2T_{n}$$ 
>   where, $T_{0} = T_{1} = 1$
>
> (a) Prove by induction that: $T_{n}$ is odd for $n ≥ 0.$

You do not need to solve the 
recurrence for this.

> (b) Prove by induction that: $$\gcd(T_{n+1}, T_{n}) = 1 \qquad\forall n ≥ 0.$$ You may assume that 
>   $T_{n}$ is odd for all $n$.

You do not need to solve the recurrence for this.

Answer (score 1):

$(a)$ Let $T_n$ is odd for $n=m+1$

Then $\displaystyle T_{m+2}=T_{m+1}+2T_m$ which is odd as for integer $\displaystyle T_m, T_{m+2}-T_{m+1}$ will be even i.e., $\displaystyle T_{m+2},T_{m+1}$ will have same parity

$(b)$  $$(T_{n+2},T_{n+1})=(T_{n+1}+2T_n,T_{n+1})=(2T_n,T_{n+1})=(T_n,T_{n+1})$$ as $T_{n+1}$ is odd

$$\implies(T_{n+2},T_{n+1})=(T_{n+1},T_n)$$ which reminds me of [Prove that any two consecutive terms of the Fibonacci sequence are relatively prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24378/prove-that-two-any-consecutive-terms-of-fibonacci-sequence-are-relatively-prime)