# Greatest Common Divisor with Fibonacci Numbers

Tags: recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers, gcd-and-lcm

Prove that for all integers $n\geq 0$:

$$\gcd(F_{n+1},F_n)=1$$

I am extremely lost. Please can some provide some hint or direction? Thank you so very much

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24378/prove-that-two-any-consecutive-terms-of-fibonacci-sequence-are-relatively-prime

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The  Euclidean algorithm, $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a-b,b)$ works well with the Fibonacci recurrence.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!