# Help with proof regarding Fibonacci sequence?

Tags: induction, fibonacci-numbers

I have to prove that
$$ F_{n}^{2} - F_{n+1}F_{n-1} = (-1)^{n} \;\;\;\;\;\;(n>1)$$

By induction, we can see this is true for $n=2$ (note that the sequence starts with $F_{0} = 1$). When proving the result for $n \ge 3$, the solution begins with
$$F_{n}^{2} - F_{n+1}F_{n-1} = F_{n}^{2} - (F_{n}+F_{n-1})F_{n-1} =  \cdot \cdot \cdot $$

Can someone please explain how we get that
$$F_{n+1}F_{n-1} = (F_{n}+F_{n-1})F_{n-1} \;?$$

It is not immediately clear to me. If we multiply out the RHS it gives
$$F_{n}F_{n-1} + F_{n-1}F_{n-1}$$
which I don't see how is equal to the LHS of the third equation I wrote. All help appreciated

Comment: Remember that $F_{n+1}=F_n+F_{n-1}$.  If you remember only one thing about the fibonacci sequence, you need to remember that.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1928409/589

Answer (score 3):

$F_{n+1}=F_n+F_{n-1}$ by definition of the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: Wow. Braindead moment from me! Thanks a lot though :)