# Fibonacci sequence proof via contraposition

Tags: proof-writing, induction, proof-explanation, fibonacci-numbers

So we know $F_{0} = 0, F_{1} = 1$, and for all $n ≥ 2, F_{n} = F_{n−1} + F_{n−2}$ for the *Fibonacci Sequence*. How do we prove that for every natural number $n$, $gcd(F_{n}, F_{n+1}) = 1$?

I can make sense that we will prove the contrapositive of the **induction step**.

And also that only the two following properties will be useful: \begin{align}
∀n ∈ N, gcd(0, n) = n \tag{I}
\\
∀n, a, b, p, q ∈ Z, n | a ∧ n | b ⇒ n | (ap + bq) \tag{II}
\end{align}

Comment: You just need to observe that $\gcd(F_{n},F_{n+1}) = \gcd(F_n, F_{n-1})$. Can you see why this is true? If not, then reply back.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Hmm, I'm honestly having a very hard time proving this one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that any two consecutive terms of the Fibonacci sequence are relatively prime](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24378/prove-that-any-two-consecutive-terms-of-the-fibonacci-sequence-are-relatively-pr)

Comment: Let $g = \gcd(F_n, F_{n+1})$. Then, $g | F_n$ and $g | F_{n+1}$. Next, $g | F_{n+1} - F_n = F_{n-1}$, by definition of Fibonacci series. Hence, $g | \gcd(F_n, F_{n-1})$ (as it divides both of them) . By induction, we assumed that $\gcd(F_n, F_{n-1}) = 1$. Then, $g=1$, so this proves that $\gcd(F_n, F_{n+1}) = 1$. This completes the induction (base case is obvious).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, the Fibonacci sequence can be written as $$F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$$ and we want to prove $$\forall n\in \mathbb{N},\ gcd(F_n,F_{n+1})=1$$
        We will let this statement be $P(n)$.

(Note that the Fibonacci sequence can also be written as $F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}+F_{n}$ and we will use this to our advantage.)

For the **base case, $n=0$**:
\begin{align*}
   gcd(F_n,F_{n+1})&=gcd(F_0,F_1)\\
   &=gcd(0,1) \\
   &=1 && \text{(Using Claim 1)}
  \end{align*}
        So **$P(0)$** holds.

Now, assuming **$P(k)$** holds for $n=k$, we let $g=gcd(F_k,F_{k+1})$.

Then $g \mid F_k \land g \mid F_{k+1}$ by the definition of the $gcd$(greatest common divisor).

By **Claim 2**,\begin{align*}
   g \mid \overbrace{F_k + F_{k+1}}^\text{their sum} \land \ g \mid \overbrace{F_{k+1}-F_k(=F_{k-1})}^\text{their difference} && \text{(by the definition of the Fibonacci sequence)}\\
  \end{align*}

So we know $ gcd(F_{k},F_{k+1})=1$ and $ gcd(F_{k-1},F_{k})=1$ by this and assuming that $P(k)$ holds.

In order to prove $P(k+1)$ for $n=k+1$, observe that:
            \begin{align*}
    gcd(F_n,F_{n+1})&=gcd(F_{k+1},F_{k+2})\\
    &=gcd(F_{k+1},F_{k+1}+F_k)\\
    &=1 && \text{(as we showed earlier using Claim 2 that the sum is also divisible)}\\
    \text{Then $g=1$.}\\
    \text{This proves $P(k+1)$.}
    \end{align*}